# Material UI Arabic Date Support

Tags: datetime, material-ui, next.js, translation

I am developing Multilanguage site "Arabic" and "English", and having trouble to apply Arabic support for the Date Picker component.

I am using following packages:

```
"@material-ui/core": "^4.11.3",
"@material-ui/icons": "^4.11.2",
"@material-ui/lab": "^4.0.0-alpha.57",
"@material-ui/pickers": "^3.3.10",
"date-fns": "^2.20.0",
```

Although, I managed to translate days and months using "date-fns", **but the years and days number not getting translated**.

[image: KeyboardDatePicker]

```
import { MuiPickersUtilsProvider, KeyboardTimePicker, KeyboardDatePicker } from '@material-ui/pickers';
import DateFnsUtils from '@date-io/date-fns';
import { arSA, enGB } from 'date-fns/locale';

<MuiPickersUtilsProvider utils={DateFnsUtils} locale={language === 'ar' ? arSA : enGB}>
 <KeyboardDatePicker
  margin="normal"
  id="end-time-picker"
  label="End Date"
  value={endDate}
  onChange={handleEndDateChange}
  KeyboardButtonProps={{
 'aria-label': 'change time',
  }}
  InputLabelProps={{
  className: classes.inputPropsTest,
  }}
  minDate={new Date()}
 />
</MuiPickersUtilsProvider>
```

Is there a way to achieve this? or am I doing something wrong?

Regards

Comment: could you do it?